# Where is the lever to open the closed door leading to the spiral staircase in the Channelwood area of Myst?

Tags: myst

It looks like there is a bug about the lever, whitch opens the closed door. But I
I couldn't even find the lever. Where is it?
Used to play Myst as a Teenager. Now I want to go throug this fascinating game again. Thanks for your help.